# Dictionary-like class that defaults to a function that does nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda

I want to parse data from a file, and for each line I want to validate each piece of data. Imagine that the first few lines of the file look something like this:

```
id|date|rate|notes
1|2016-07-23|0.765|foo
2|2016-07-23|0.432| 
1|2016-07-24|0.697|bar
```

I want to make sure that the `date` and `rate` values are valid, and I have functions that can check that they are. These functions return a value if the input is valid, and throw an error if it's not. E.g:

```
def validate_date(string):
    parts = [int(x) for x in string.split("-")
    return datetime.date(*parts)
```

I don't care about the values of the `id` or `notes` fields. So I can do this:

```
validators = dict()
validators['id'] = lambda x: x 
validators['date'] = validate_date
validators['rate'] = validate_rate
validators['notes'] = lambda x: x
```

Then, once I've read in each row (as a dictionary) I can validate each field like so:

```
output = dict()
for key, value in line.iteritems()
    output[key] = validators[key](value)
return output
```

Which is all great. The problem is that the file I want to parse actually has dozens of fields that I don't care about, and only a handful that I do. So, instead of manually having to define a line like `validators['id'] = lambda x: x`, what I'd like to do is use something like a `defaultdict` to return a function that simply returns the input. But, if I try:

```
def do_nothing(x):
    return x

foo = defaultdict(do_nothing)
foo['bar'](1)
```

I get the error: `do_nothing() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.

Is there a way to create something that is like a `defaultdict`, but that returns an object that can take an argument?

Comment: Did you intend to write `lambda: do_nothing`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `defaultdict` returns whatever was created by its default function so all you need is for `do_nothing` to return a callable that takes one param. You don't really need `do_nothing` at all, just

```
 validators = collections.defaultdict(lambda: lambda x: x)
```

Now `defaultdict` returns `lambda x: x` which takes one parameter so you can do

```
validators['foo'](1)
```

and the lambda is called with `1`.

Comment: I need use `lambda: lambda x: x`, but thanks. That's what I needed.